# Getting array input from first class to another

Tags: java

I've been using getters and setters in this java code .. so in my Class `A` I get the user input and I tried this and it runs perfect and I tried to output the user input and the answer is same so I've go to the Class `B`  in class `B` I need to search .. the user will search and output the answer if true .. in class `A`

example the user input Student id : 12 and he searched it in class `B` it must output ..

but my problem I don't know how I can link the array from the Class `A` to Class `B` so I can manage to search is ..

Comment: What do you mean by "link the array". Can you post some code for A and B showing us what you are trying to do?

Comment: Check this, maybe it will help you > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462163/java-how-to-access-an-arraylist-of-another-class

Comment: System.out.print("ENTER NAME: ");
          mskt[rec.a].setName(br.readLine());
          System.out.print("ENTER ID: ");
          mskt[rec.a].setId(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
          System.out.print("ENTER MATH GRADE: ");
//i ask the user to input and store the value at int a .. int a is declared as global .. i want to search =its values in class B

Comment: Please don't try to put this much code in a comment.  Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: sorry sir im just new in this forum

Comment: I suggest you add all the relevant code to your post. You will get better help faster if it's possible to "see" what you're doing.

Comment: i declared this : rec[] mskt=new rec[10]; and mskt[rec.a]=new rec(); in my class A ?? // rec is my class and mskt is my object .. i dont know how can i access this on Class B ?? so i can use it to search and what should i declare on class B ?

Comment: Why do you insist on not editing your post? Add your code to your post as it is please!

Answer (score 0):

You can *pass* an array to a method call, like this:

```
// void someMethod(String[] someStringArray);
String[] theArray = new String[]{"foo", "bar"};
someMethod(theArray);
```

or to some constructor:

```
// SomeClass(String[] someStringArray);
String[] theArray = new String[]{"foo", "bar"};
SomeClass foobar = new SomeClass(theArray);
```

see also, [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: in class A i declared this :rec[] mskt=new rec[10];
mskt[rec.a]=new rec();
/rec is the class name , mskt is object name .. im not sure how can i access this in class B ?